# Postgresl jsonb_array_elements to json array

Tags: postgresql

I have jsonb column in the db table which contains jsonb array and want to select one element from each array object. Given try using jsonb_array_elements but no luck.

```
{
      "tags" : [
        {
          "identifier" : "NewArrival",
          "translation" : {
            "en_US" : "New Arrival",
            "en_CA" : "New Arrivals"
          }
        },
        {
          "identifier" : "FreshNewArrival",
          "translation" : {
            "en_US" : "Fresh Arrival",
            "en_CA" : "Fresh Arrivals"
          }
        },
        {
          "identifier" : "UpdatedArrival",
          "translation" : {
            "en_US" : "Updated Arrival",
            "en_CA" : "Updated Arrivals"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

just want to fetch one element of each array as a resulting array

```
select jsonb_array_elements(cp.product_data -> 'tags') -> 'translations' -> 'en_US' from tags
```

column_name -> 'tags' -> 'translation' -> 'en_US'

```
['New Arrival', 'Fresh Arrival', 'Updated Arrival']
```

Comment: SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_array_elements(cp.product_data -> 'tags')->'translation'->>'en_US') AS result_array
FROM tags;

Comment: Do you want an array (`text[]`) or a json array (`json`) as the result?

Comment: It's `-> 'translation'` not `-> 'translations'`, but otherwise your code should just work. What exactly is the issue you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

You've already solved it kind of. This query will work.

```
SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements(cp.product_data -> 'tags') -> 'translation' -> 'en_US'
    FROM table_name
);
```